# Unable to run pygame script on windows

Tags: python, windows, pygame, packaging

So I have been looking around how to run python scripts on windows, but I'm unable to run pygame scripts using windows xp 64 bits on a virtual machine. I've tried simply running it with different versions of python, pyinstaller, py2exe and cx_freeze .

My main problem is that i'm not sure what the problem really is. For example: when I run the script like normal (using python and nothing else ) the script opens a cmd window but instantly closes it again, but when I try first transforming it to an .exe file I get an error saying the file is valid, but is for another machine type ( pretty sure this has to do with 32 bit and 64bit python but i'm not sure how to fix it ) and when I run it from the cmd I get an error saying there's no module named pygame.
I've also noticed that when simply transfering the raw game.py file some of the code seems to get messed up and becomes all one straight line ( i've forgotten what the name for the cause of this error is ).

Here's the entire code for the game i'm trying to run :

```
import sys, pygame, pygame.mixer, time
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
w = 1 
while w == 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    shotgunsound = pygame.mixer.Sound("shotgun.wav")


    size = width, height = 600,400

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)


    bird = pygame.image.load("bird.png")
    shotgun = pygame.image.load("fps_sprite_shotgun.png")
    post = pygame.image.load("post.png")
    ground = pygame.image.load("ground.png")
    text2 = pygame.image.load("text2.png")
    pygame.display.flip()
    skyblue = 0,125,200

    x = 0
    y = 100
    screen.blit(bird,(x,y))

    z = 1
    while z == 1:
        mx,my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and  mx > 400 and mx < 560 and my >100 and my <300:
                shotgunsound.play()
                z = 0
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                shotgunsound.play()

        screen.fill(skyblue)
        screen.blit(bird,(x,y))
        screen.blit(shotgun,(mx-300,my-200))
        screen.blit(post,(400,100))
        screen.blit(ground,(0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()
        x = x+1
        time.sleep(.01)
        if x == 400:
            screen.blit(text2,(0,0))
            pygame.display.flip()
            time.sleep(3)
            sys.exit()
    text1 = pygame.image.load("text1.png")

    screen.blit(text1, (0,0))

    pygame.display.flip()
    n = 1

    while n == 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                n = 0
    x = 0
    rpg = pygame.image.load("fps_sprite_rpg.png")
    w = 0
mx,my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
t = 1
mx,my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
green = 0,100,0
building = pygame.image.load("building.png")
rpgsound = pygame.mixer.Sound("rpg.wav")
while t ==1:
    mx,my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                             sys.exit()
                elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                  sys.exit()
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and mx > 400 and mx < 600 and my > 100 and my < 300:
            rpgsound.play()
            t = 0
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            rpgsound.play()
    screen.fill(green)
    screen.blit(bird,(x,y))
    screen.blit(building,(400,50))
    screen.blit(rpg,(mx-300,my-200))
    x = x+1
    pygame.display.flip()
    if x == 400:
        screen.blit(text2,(0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()
        time.sleep(3)
        sys.exit()

final = pygame.image.load("FINAL.png")
screen.blit(final,(0,0))
pygame.display.flip()
time.sleep(3)
sys.exit()
```

Any help either identifying the problems or even helping me fix them would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you actually installed `pygame` on your computer?

Comment: Maybe it's because you have several `while` loops and event loops.

Comment: i've had problems installing pygame , but i think it's installed . It also shoudln't matter when I run the converted exe file since they're supposed to work even without python installed

Comment: no it's not because of the while loops, the script runs perfectly on linux

Answer (score 0):

Well it's rather long code but my first suggestion would be to try to get rid of some of those while loops. Your never actually looping because you make your loop expressions false through the first iteration of the loop. Well actually, on second look you do some funky things. You might be misunderstanding the compiler. Your code reads from top to bottom. It will not just jump all over the place. I think you were trying to almost pause your loop by doing `x=0` and then resume with `x+=1`.

Secondly, in game loops I like to do this: `while True:`. I guess that's a preference thing but that's just me.

Thirdly inside of a `while x == 1:` you have a if statement saying `if x == 400:`. That is impossible to return true on that if statement.

There's a lot of suggestions I could make be I recommend that you start by expanding your knowledge on the basic functions of python before you get started on pygame. Hope it helps.

Comment: yes i know the code is bad, but it was my first game and i coded it all in about 5 hours straight. I seriously can't remember why I used so many while loops, all I know is it works perfectly on linux but I just can't get it to run on windows.

Comment: Ok i'll try to recheck the problem

Comment: I appreciate the help. I have to go, but tomorrow i'll check back and also probably spend several hours on this issue. ( also feel free to suggest improvements to the code )